# Find method returns false but I can still use the delete method Phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

I was testing the way of deleting records/objects with [Phalcon](https://olddocs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/index.html)(3.1.1) and I wondered why the code below does not provide an error message when the `Phalcon\Mvc\Model::find()` method returns false.

```
$someObjectIDs[] = 0;

// Find related objects by ids
$ObjectsToRemove = FooBar::find([
    'id NOT IN ('.implode(', ', $someObjectIDs).')'
]);

// Delete
$ObjectsToRemove->delete();
```

If I dumb the result of the `Phalcon\Mvc\Model::delete()` method, this will also be true if the `Phalcon\Mvc\Model::find()` method returns false. Why should Phalcon always check the results of the `Phalcon\Mvc\Model::find()` method in the documentation first before deleting them?

This is what Phalcon does in the [documentation](https://olddocs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.1/reference/models.html).

```
$robot = Robots::find();

if ($robot !== false) {
    if ($robot->delete() === false) {
      ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest updating your Phalcon library to most recent version.

In recent release find method would return you instance of [`Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple`](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.3/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model_Resultset_Simple) where you can use `count()` or `valid()` method to verify number of records found.

Example:

```
    /** @var \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple $instance */
    $instance = \MyModel::find([
        'conditions' => 'id IN (:ids:)',
        'bind' => [
            'ids' => implode([2, 3, 4, 5])
        ],
    ]);
    if($instance->valid()){
        $instance->delete();
    }
```